# Why is the main character losing even though he goes first, python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
Krotos = [100, 25]

Sephiroth = [100, 25]

endGame = 0

def checkHealth():
  global endGame
  if Krotos[0] == 0:
    print("Game Over")
    endGame = 1
  if Sephiroth[0] == 0:
    print("You Win")
    endGame = 1

def krotosAttack():
  Sephiroth[0] -= Krotos[1]

def sephirothAttack():
  Krotos[0] -= Sephiroth[1]

while endGame == 0:
  krotosAttack()
  checkHealth()
  while endGame == 0:
    sephirothAttack()
    checkHealth()
```

Just so you know I am new to python. I wanted to make a text-based game but when I run the while loop it says that Krotos loses even though he goes first and they have the same health and damage.

Comment: The inner while loop repeats and sephiroth will definitely die first. You might want to do that in a single while loop

Comment: Your IDE will have a step-by-step debugger to track this kind of problem

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx. Sephiroth will win because he depletes his opponent's hp

Comment: This is a nice, clearly stated question with a legitimate attempt shown. +1. It's nice to see a beginner following site rules and asking well. Keep up the good work and you won't stay a beginner for long.

Comment: @MadPhysicist my bad.. Krotos will die first as he said, the **first one to move**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the last block.
1)  It enters the outer loop.
2)  Krotos makes one attack.
3)  It enters the inner loop.
4)  Sephiroph makes an attack
5)  Since the game isn't over, it then goes back to the start of the inner loop.

So unless Krotos wins on his first attack, Sephiroph gets to keep attacking until the game ends.

To fix, change the inner while to an if.